I want to show video on second screen of Android Summi with a program of Android Java and calling it from flutter, how can I do for this?
I want to show video on second screen of Android Summi-D2 with a program of Android(Java) and calling it from flutter, how can I do for this?
I want to show video on second screen of Android Summi-D2 with a program of Android Java and calling it from flutter, how can I do for this?
